# how to create table relationship diagram in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, joomla

I want to create table relationship diagram in phpmyadmin. Anyone is there for the solution?

Other necessary details

Apache Version :2.2.22
PHP Version    :5.4.3
MySQL Version  :5.5.24

Wamp Version 2.2

Database Version    5.5.24-log

Database Collation  utf8_general_ci

PHP Version     5.4.3

Web Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3

WebServer to PHP Interface  apache2handler

Joomla! Version     Joomla! 2.5.8 Stable [ Ember ] 8-November-2012 14:00 GMT

Joomla! Platform Version    Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable [ Brian Kernighan ] 03-Jan-2012 00:00 GMT

User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/generating-erd-using-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [export via phpmyadmin](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export) to export your database in `SQL` format.
Then run this file on your `mysql client`.

Then try the [mysql workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/?current_os=src) for creating the relationship diagram.

Comment: if mysql workbench does not work properly than uninstalling of it, will be effect on my current site database and structure?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, it does not affect your database as you are creating new seprate database for this purpose